# setting focus to specific item in a listbox using javascript

Tags: javascript

i want to set the focus but not the focus of the page to that element
i mean when the user slides down then that specific item appears in focus

Comment: a bit unclear - can you try and give an actual scenario?

Comment: You really need to provide more information, what's your definition of focus?  User input, or attracting attention to a specific area?  Do you mean whilst scrolling?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Andy: infact i have a list box at the end of the page and there is a list of categories init , this is infact an edit page.
i want dat the selected category wub be in focus(in view) when the user scrolls the page to the list of categories

Answer (score 0):

Does this come close to what you mean?
http://jsbin.com/obori/2

In this there is a very basic hide/show of paragraphs.